# Labwindows fails to compile- says it is missing a dll that is already in project

Tags: c, opencv, labwindows

I'm trying to use openCV with LabWindows 2012SP1. I've got a simple project attempting to run a simple "Hello World" program in debug mode.

The code I'm trying to run is

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

// Create a window to show the image
cvNamedWindow( "My Cool Window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE  );
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 300, 100 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3 );
 
double hScale = 1.0;
double vScale = 1.0;
double shear  = 0.0;
int lineWidth = 2;
 
// Initialize the font
CvFont font;
cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX, hScale, vScale, shear, lineWidth, 8 );
 
// Write on the image ...
CvScalar color = CV_RGB( 0, 51, 102 );
cvPutText( img, "Hello World!", cvPoint( 60, 60 ), &font, color );
 
// ... and show it to the world !
cvShowImage( "My Cool Window", img );
 
// Wait until the user wants to exit
cvWaitKey(0);
```

and I have the following libraries added:

> opencv_core247d.lib (32-bit)
>
> opencv_highgui247d.lib (32-bit)
>
> opencv_imgproc247d.lib (32-bit)
>
> opencv_imgproc247d.dll

However, when I go to run the program in debug mode, I get an error telling me:

> The program can't start because opencv_imgproc247d.dll is missing
> from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I'm more than a little bit confused at this point, as I have the DLL in question added to the project.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you need to add the location of the opencv dll's to the 'PATH' env var.
- please *don't* use the old c-api (won't be supported in near future), ( IplImages, cv* functions ). use cv::Mat and the c++ api(namespace cv) instead.

Comment: LabWindows is C only- is it possible to use c++ functions with a c only environment? If it is, I'll switch them right away.

Comment: no, c != c++. please hint the LabWindows ppl at [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/) (they' ve been living under a rock for too long)

Comment: The hope is to get away from LabWindows in general, but for now I have to work with it. That did fix the issue, many thanks!